# Time series/animated heatmaps with big vector tile datasets and Mapbox GL JS

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, webgl, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on a project using big point datasets (as much as several hundred thousand points displayed at the same time) rendered as an animated heatmap in the browser with Pixi.JS, on top of Google Maps. The points have a timestamp and are filtered dynamically, on the client side, following a time range filter.

This approach is starting to show its limits in terms of performance (huge CPU bottleneck), so I'm looking at a Mapbox GL JS based solution to render those points.

So far I have been unsuccessful in getting a smooth animation with that many points, looking at 3 different approaches:

1. Updating displayed points with `setFilter`:

`map.setFilter('layer', ['all', ['>', 'datetime', t0], ['<', 'datetime', t1]])`

2. Using `setPaintProperty` and GL JS expressions to change visual attributes of the points:

`map.setPaintProperty('layer', 'circle-radius', [
            'case',
            ['<', ['number', ['get', 'datetime']], t],
            5,
            ['>', ['number', ['get', 'datetime']], t],
            0,
            0
        ])`

Both of those approaches are slow, or rather, some acceptable framerate is reachable but there is a huge lag between user interaction and visual update.

3. Ryan Baumann advises here to rather update the input dataset with `setData`: [MapBox GL JS marker/icon animation slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356979/mapbox-gl-js-marker-icon-animation-slow-performance)

The problem with that approach is that it is not realistically applicable to big datasets that come in vector tiles form. Even trying with a big GeoJSON file, the result is as slow as the two first approaches.

I am ready to explore some kind of custom renderer/shader that could sit between my vector tiles and Mapbox GL JS, but custom webGL layer types seem to be in development limbo:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/281

Thanks

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at 'deck.gl' that advertises good results with large datasets overlayed to mapboxgl maps. I don't have direct experience with it, so I can really say more.

https://github.com/uber/deck.gl

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely a path I'm considering more and more. I was put off initially by the lack of support for tiled data (https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/issues/905), but one can work around that. I'll let you know how this goes.